# request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status. on Spring Boot

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot

I having blocked by CORS on the client side, so I added these configuration on spring boot to allow api calls on my react app:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000");
    }
}
```

Then this is my api call on my React app:

```
  const res = await axios({
    method: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:8080/login",
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    },
    data: {
      username,
      password,
    },
  });
```

However I'm still getting blocked by CORS error

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use this "**WebSecurityConfig**"

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private final JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    public WebSecurityConfig(JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint, UserDetailsService userDetailsService, JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter) {
        this.jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint = jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.jwtRequestFilter = jwtRequestFilter;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // configure AuthenticationManager so that it knows from where to load
        // user for matching credentials
        // Use BCryptPasswordEncoder
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                /*.and()
                .cors()*/
                .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/authenticate","/notification/*","/actuator/*","/actuator")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/app/*","/topic/*","/exchange/*")
                .authenticated()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        http.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you it solved my CORS error, I only needed to disable cors(). However what if I want to allow specific origins? instead of disabling everything.

Also when doing login authentication POST request I'm getting 403 forbidden.

Comment: for specific allowed origin

 @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("https://example.com"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }